# “waste time" and " pass time"

Tags: differences, language-formation

In this sentence, why people say "if reading is to accomplish anything more than passing time, it must be active?" Why isn't "wasting time" a right answer?

Answer (score 4):

If I have half an hour before my next scheduled appointment, I have the choice of undertaking a task from my to-do list (such as filing) or picking up a novel and reading.

I am very happy to *pass the time* immersed in a book; I derive simple pleasure from reading even if there is no obvious tangible benefit. If you have to complete the task that I left undone, then you may consider that I *wasted* that 30 minutes. I do not.

The choice between the two words reflects different value positions. *Wasting time* is almost invariably a negative description; *passing time* is at worst neutral and often positive.

Answer (score 0):

[***Wasting time***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/waste+of+time) means you have better things to do, for example lounging around when you have work to do.

[***Passing time***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+time) means you are unable to spend the time on better things, and are forced to do something that's not so great, for example reading tabloids while waiting in the boarding lounge.